# Servlet not loading on startup in webphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, web.xml, websphere-8

I am having an issue where my eQMIUIInitServlet is not gettting loaded on startup.
eQInitServlet is getting loaded on startup but eQMIUIInitServlet is not getting loaded .
The same application is working fine on Tomcat.
Here is my web.xml file.

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>eQInitServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.eqtechnologic.eqube.eQInitServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- Load this servlet at server startup time -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>eQMIUIInitServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.eQMIUIInitServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- Load this servlet at server startup time -->
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
```

Comment: Are you using WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: No. I am not using Websphere Liberty. I have Websphere 8.5.5 .

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the logs.

Comment: How you can tell that servlet is not starting? I created simple test and it works fine on 8.5.5. You should see messages in the log like `SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module` and then `SRVE0242I: [EARName] [/context] [HelloServlet]: Initialization successful.` and finally `WSVR0221I: Application started: EARName`.

Comment: Actually after trying a lot i found out that the servlet was not getting loaded due to some jars in shared library.After removing those jars its worked fine.